# Can a finitely generated free group be isomorphic to a non-trivial quotient of itself?

Tags: gr.group-theory

I'm never sure about free groups whether a question is easy or not. It feels to me like this is impossible, but I couldn't come up with any argument.

If $F_n$ is a free group on $n$ generators, could there exist a non-trivial $N\triangleleft F_n$ such that $F_n/N \cong F_n$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the free groups are [Hopfian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_group) because they are [residually finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the term Hopfian before!

Comment: And free groups are residually finite because, by a simple application of the ping-pong lemma, they can be embedded into $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @Alain: this is not the easiest proof. Consider $F_2= < a,b >$ and any reduced word $w=c_1c_2...c_n\ne 1$ in $F_2$, $c_i\in \{a,b,a^{-1}, b^{-1}\}$. The letters $a,b$ produce two partial permutations of the set $\{0,1,...,n\}$: $c_i$ takes $i-1$ to $i$. Complete these partial permutations to full permutations $\alpha, \beta$. And let $G$ be the (finite) subgroup of $S_{n+1}$ generated by $\alpha, \beta$. Let $\phi$ be the homomorphism $F_2\to G$ taking $a$ to $\alpha$, $b$ to $\beta$. Then the image of $w$ is not the trivial permutation because $\phi(w)$ takes $0$ to $n$. 

Comment: @ Mark: I respectfully disagree. The ping-pong argument gives, in a completely elementary way, a faithful representation of $F_2$ into $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, which yields much more than residual finiteness.

Comment: @Alain: this argument also gives more than residual finiteness. For example, it gives LERF. But of course being in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is also important. 

Comment: I think Mark provided O. Schreier's original proof. Both proofs are quite elementary and of independent interest. Being of very different flavor (automaton-theoretic vs using matrix groups and elementary arithmetic), it's hard to call one easier (it's really a matter of taste).